# returning sql array in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am having trouble in returning data in php from an SQL query. here is my code:

```
      public function get_audit_message($productId,$accountId)
        {
        $sql_list  ="SELECT notes
                     FROM  ".$this->tables_audit."
                     WHERE productId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($productId)."'
                     AND accountId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($accountId)."'
                     ";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql_list);
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
            $return = $query->result_array();
            return $return;
            }
        else return false;
        }
```

the reason I am having trouble is that as it is at `return $return;` returns the correct number of results but only displays the word "array". then if i change it to `return $return[0];` returns the first entry of information correctly.

So what i want to be able to do is select all array numbers e.g `return $return[*];` if only was possible.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several easy ways to display content of PHP Array in HTML.

The most simple is to view it via **print_r** command like this:

```
print_r ($my_array);
```

If you need to be "nice" formatted, add PRE tag like this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

or like this:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($my_array, 1)."</pre>";
```

Also, there is similar **var_dump** and **var_export** PHP function:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($my_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

or

```
echo "<pre>";
var_export($my_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Just choose your preferred stile.

Answer (score 1):

`return $return;` is the correct way to return an array from this function, but you can't just `echo()` the return value, since it's an array. When you try to echo an array, you get just the literal word "Array" (this also raises a notice which you would've seen with error reporting turned on).

You have to iterate over it and print each array element out, or use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$array = $obj->get_audit_message($productId,$accountId); // However you call it
echo implode( "<br />\n", $array) . "<br />\n";
```

Or:

```
$array = $obj->get_audit_message($productId,$accountId); // However you call it
foreach( $array as $el) {
    echo $el . "<br />\n";
}
```

Both of the above snippets will produce the exact same output.